# I would like to put together tokens and the associated type of word (nouns, adjective, verbs etc)

Tags: r, dictionary, token, tokenize

How can I do it? I've found tokens with tokens functions and the types od words with the function tokens_lookup and the dictionary.. I would like to print the results together,
associating each token with the token and type of word, if verb, name, etc.
Can you take me an example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read
[what this site is about](https://stackoverflow.com/about) and 
"[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)" 
before asking a question.

Comment: This is too broad. Maybe start with [cleanNLP](https://github.com/statsmaths/cleanNLP) or [spacyr](https://github.com/kbenoit/spacyr)